# Ember: How to link to sections and actions (without nesting routes)

Tags: url, ember.js, routes

Let's say that I have a blog where each post can have several sections and comments and I'd like to use a hard-links to navigate and operate on this. There are several samples using some pseudo-code, of course they doesn't work, just demonstring my intends :)

Of course `/blog.html#/posts/1` uses `PostRoute`, `PostController` etc and uses `:post_id` for finding object - that's obvoius.

1. How can I pass (and then access) additional params which doesn't change the controller but I can use them to navigation. ie `/blog.html#/posts/1?section=123` should use the same route, controller and view as it was just `Post`, but I'd like to read the `section` and just navigate to section with `#123`
2. `/blog.html#/posts/1/?comments=456` - actually should behave like `section` from point 1, but navigates to comment and optionally add some class to the container.
3. Other case: I'd like to go to section `123` AND additionally `edit` it with link like: `/blog.html#/posts/1?section=123&action=edit`. Now I'm using a button with an action like `{{action editSection section}}` and `{{#if isEdit}}` but I'd like to be able to reflect this in URL and also go to this state from URL (de facto my post can have several different modes not only preview/edit, therefore it should be accesible by the link).

I hope that cases makes sense, TBH I have no idea in which direction should I go. Tried with nested routes, but I'd like to avoid changing the controller. Also have no concept how to reflect the action in the URL...

I'm using **Ember 1.1.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the model method of the route to handle such parameters, separate them from the model parameter and set the appropriate controller state.
Another approach would be to use nested routes that will render un-nested views(and controllers) - as explained towards the bottom [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/).

Comment: Thx, will try to do something with your tips ;)

Comment: you might also find this interesting:
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ember-query-string